# Error 500 when upload Codeigniter to server

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a CMS written by CI. And when i upload code to server it return:

```
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
```

And into apache server it show error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Exception

Message: Session: Configured save path 'C:\Windows\temp' is not writable by the PHP process.

Filename: D:\my_website\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 124

Backtrace:

File: D:\my_website\application\controllers\content.php
Line: 4
Function: __construct 

File: D:\my_website\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

how do i fix it? Thank all!

Comment: Well.. `Configured save path 'C:\Windows\temp' is not writable by the PHP process` - what can you do about that?

Answer (score 0):

You naeed to make `C:\Windows\temp` path writable

Answer (score 0):

You have to give write permission to `C:\Windows\temp`.